# Android NoClassDefFoundError crash after new couchbase Lite Jars added

Tags: android, gradle, couchbase, crashlytics, fabric.io

The the same crash happened after I imported Couchbase Lite Android using either Gradle or jars.

Couldn't really figure out what's going on here as I didn't touch the code and only dropped the jars into the "libs" folder.

```
// inside Custom Application class
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());   // <===== Crash here!
}
```

**Trace:**

```
07-07 19:37:43.785  15247-15247/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sg.com.bigspoon.www, PID: 15247
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:202)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:197)
        at sg.com.bigspoon.www.data.BigSpoon.onCreate(BigSpoon.java:121)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4541)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**
Although this is "fixed". But it is still very bizarre why this is happening. I would enlighten me and I would mark it as correct answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by enabling multiDex in build.gradle

```
android {

     defaultConfig {
         // Lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         minSdkVersion 14 

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**SOURCE and more details -->**

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/136
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Although this is "fixed". But it is still very bizarre why this is happening. I would enlighten me and I would mark it as correct answer instead.